# Using pycaret's preprocessing on unseen dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-preprocessing, train-test-split

I'm thoroughly enjoying pycaret to handle much of the legwork in my analysis.  I'm making heavy use of the `setup()` method in preprocessing to handle normalization, target transformation, and feature selection in my data.  After running my train/test, I'm aiming to run the model on an unseen dataset to mimic a real world application.  It would be nice to make use of the pycaret preprocessing to handle the unseen dataset.

Towards datascience has [a great tutorial on analysis with pycaret here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-complete-data-analysis-workflow-in-python-pycaret-9a13c0fa51d4) but after using a variety of transformations in the preprocessing setup method, they appear to just feed the raw `data_unseen` set into the `predict_model()` method without any obvious preparation.  Is there a way to use pycaret's preprocessor on subsequent datasets that aren't train/test splits?  Or do we need to do it without pycaret?

Here is their code:

```
import pandas as pddf = pd.read_csv('source/heart.csv')
df.head()

data = df.sample(frac=0.95, random_state=42)
data_unseen = df.drop(data.index)

data.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
data_unseen.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

print('Data for Modeling: ' + str(data.shape))
print('Unseen Data For Predictions: ' + str(data_unseen.shape))

Data for Modeling: (288, 14)
Unseen Data For Predictions: (15, 14)

from pycaret.classification import *
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
model = setup(data = data, target = 'output', normalize = True, normalize_method='minmax', train_size = 0.8,fix_imbalance = True, fix_imbalance_method=RandomOverSampler(), session_id=123)

best = compare_models()
tuned_best = tune_model(best)

plot_model(tuned, plot = 'pr')

final_best = finalize_model(tuned_best)

predict_model(final_best)

predict_model(final_best, data = data_unseen)
```

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.